# Keep some variables initialized on destroy()

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app that requires fairly substantial initialization (CPU-wise, not memory). When the user hits the back button, I'd prefer to leave the hard computations and allocated structures intact so there is no 3-4 second delay every time they hit the icon.

What is the proper way to do this? Should part of the app be a service?

Comment: Why not to show a splash screen while your app is being initialized? If the user presses back during that time you abort the initialization. You can do initialization in a non-UI fragment with setRetainInstance(true) so that it does not stop if user changes orientation.

Comment: Yeah I will use a splash screen, but my question pertains to re-doing the same effort every time the app is put into the background.

Comment: yes cache it somewhere, not sure what you're doing but a background service or a singleton / static cache.

Comment: What exactly do you initialize? Most data [can be saved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState) to avoid initialization each time.

Comment: @StenSoft I have to load native libraries that perform device hardware checks that take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decouple your UI and core logic. Since you want your application keep running in the background implement a service component and maintain the state of your native library initialisation and other stuff which you wanted to be available for the UI. Service plus a state machine approach will give you better benefit in such cases.

Comment: Okay, so this is the proper use of a service portion of an app: to maintain some states in the background. I had the UI and core logic already decoupled anticipating something like this, thank you for answering.